# Facebook test app stopped working, production app works fine (using JS SDK)

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I have a FB app that my website uses for the FB Login button. This app has been public for some time, and works great in production. I created a test app for my dev environments, and this too has been *working fine until last week*, when I suddenly started seeing this message in the browser console:

`Application Error: There was a problem getting data for the application you requested. The application may not be valid, or there may be a temporary glitch. Please try again later.`

This happens after I call `FB.init()` -- a call to `FB.getLoginStatus()` triggers this error, and the callback passed to `FB.getLoginStatus()` is never invoked. Again, this only happens in my development environments, not production, although the XFBML button still triggers a popup.

I [copied the basic SDK code from FB's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web), placed it in its own page, and still have this problem, so it is not something on my website's pages that is interfering.

I've tried searching SO/Google for answers, but the only real information I get is from back in 2011/12/13 and involved FB apps being in development mode; mine is not, it is public. I've tried creating a new test app and changing the FB ID that my website uses, but I get the same result.

The only change to (all) of my environments made recently is that they're all using SSL by default. Could this possibly be the cause? And if so, why would it work in my production environment but not in my development environments? Any insight is much appreciated.

EDIT: Using SDK v2.4, if that matters.

EDIT 2: This only seems to happen if the user is not logged into FB *at all*. If they have logged in externally, the SDK seems to recognize that and the call to `FB.getLoginStatus()` works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's a Facebook bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/252572561775079/

Comment: Thanks yellowaj! If this fixes my issue tomorrow I'll mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check that your Facebook app is "live and available to all users" and not in development mode, otherwise you'll get this error.

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ > open your app > App Review > "Make [App Name] public?" > YES